# Sum of binomial coefficients problem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, arithmetic

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative integers such that, for any integer $n \geq 2$ with $0 \leq x_k \leq n$, $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{x_k} = 2^n$$
How to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n+1-2x_k}{n+1-x_k}\binom{n}{x_k} = 1$$ ?

Comment: Is there more than one such sequence?  $x_k=k$ works, of course, anything else?  If there is another one, what are the first few terms?  Or are you saying that the $x_k$ can be functions of $n$?  The first time you posted this question you wanted the relation to hold for all $n$.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? People here like to see the effort you made.

Comment: Obviously any sequence $(x_n)$ that contains all the integers between $0$ and $n$ works, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true at all, even if the $x_k$ are functions of $n$.  For instance, with $n=2$ we could take $x_0=2,x_1=1,x_2=2$.  That would make your second sum equal to $\frac {2+1-4}{2+1-2}\times 1+\frac {2+1-2}{2+1-1}\times 2+\frac {2+1-4}{2+1-2}\times 1=-1$ .  Did you leave off some assumptions?

Comment: Actually there was a mistake i corrected.

Comment: So you do want it to hold for all $n$?  That's what I asked you in your first comment.  In that case, my first question applies:  is there another sequence that works besides the obvious one, $x_k=k$?

Comment: I don't know, i guess not. But I don't know how to prove that it is the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. If it were true, we should be able to replace any $x_k$ by $n-x_k$; this doesn’t change the first sum and thus shouldn’t change the second sum. But it does, as you can see e.g. by replacing $x_k=0$ by $x_k=n$.

Comment: (corrected mistake)

Comment: @user8309168: I don't see that you corrected a mistake. You replaced "a given" by "any"; but I showed that it doesn't hold for any $n$.